# How to generate model fields on rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have run

```
rails generate Model Profile name:string
```

It have worked and generated all the files. 
When I see the profile.rb file though it only has the class declaration not the fields.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Do I have to add all the fields manually ?

Comment: You add the fields in the file called `db/migrate/<date>_<model_name>.rb`. Then when the table is created and Rails is run, the fields from the table are automatically available (as Sergio mentioned)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't to add fields manually. ActiveRecord will discover them at runtime from the table structure. This is part of rails magic :)